# Inno Setup MS Access 2010 silent install

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, inno-setup

I want to create an installer for Access 2010 runtime using Inno Setup.

When I try to compile the file I get this error from Inno Setup:

> File: xxxx\config.xml
>   Line 1:
>   Unrecognized parameter name ""

I have created the recommended `config.xml` file as follows (actually I just copied it verbatim).

**config.xml file:**

```xml
<Configuration Product="AccessRT">
        <Display Level="Basic" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
        <Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="IfNeeded" />
</Configuration>
```

**Inno Setup file:**

```
#include <idp.iss>

[Files]
Source: C:\Users\john.eggHeadLtd\OneDrive\blueEggShare\config.xml; \
    DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe /extract:{tmp}\AccRT; 
#include "config.xml"
Filename: {tmp}\setup.exe; Parameters: /config {tmp}\config.xml;
Filename: {tmp}\accsp2.exe
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { Let's download two zipfiles from my website.. }
  idpaddfile('https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/0/260AA63A-A275-4A92-950D-CE20B490D0B9/AccessRuntime.exe',expandconstant('{tmp}\accRt.exe'));
  idpaddfile('https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/C/2/CC28BC00-1AF0-44B9-8A5D-9D8C8E4899BB/accessrtsp2010-kb2687444-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe',expandconstant('{tmp}\accSp2.exe'));

  { Start the download after the "Ready to install" screen is shown }
  idpdownloadafter(wpReady);
end;
```

Comment: Where does the `{tmp}\setup.exe` come from?

Comment: Martin, I thought the {tmp}\setup.exe referred to the setup.exe file produced when the {tmp}\AccRt.exe was expanded.

Comment: Make sense, I was expecting that. But it's not obvious from your question.

Comment: Also the `CurStepChanged` procedure does not make any sense. You just copy the two files to each other (what probably fails anyway) => I'm removing that from your question, not to confuse others.

Comment: And the `Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe /extract:{tmp}\AccRT;` is also wrong, it should be `Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe; Parameters: /extract:{tmp}\AccRT;`, right?

Comment: Martin that seems to be a problem.  I created the Inno Setup installer first without the 'config.xml' and in the [RUN] section used:

Comment: I tried:[Run]

 Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe /extract:{tmp}\AccRT; 
Filename: {tmp}\AccRt; Parameters: /config {tmp}\config.xml;

 Filename: {tmp}\accsp2.exe /extract:{tmp}\Accsp2; 
Filename: {tmp}\accsp2; Parameters: /config {tmp}\config.xml;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to extract the `AccessRuntime.exe` (which you download/save to `{tmp}\accRt.exe`):

```
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\accRt.exe; Parameters: /extract:{tmp}\accRt /quiet
```

Then you have to run the extracted `setup.exe` with your configuration file:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\source\path\config.xml; DestDir: {tmp}

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\accRt\setup.exe; Parameters: "/config ""{tmp}\config.xml"""
```

---

Few comments to my modifications of your code:

- the `ignoreversion` flag does not have any effect for .xml files
- You better wrap the path to the configuration file to quotes, in case `{tmp}` contains spaces.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reply.  I followed your instruction and the program compiled successfully.  In answer to your question "why do you include the config.xml" the answer is because I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: @zx485 Martin Prikryl:  The above program using the corrections suggested tries to install the temporary files in C:\users\admin\apdata\local\temp\xxxx instead of C:\Windows\Temp\xxxx resulting in an error message as C:\users\admin\apdata\local\ doesn't exist.  How do I get the iss file to temporarily copy to C:\Windows\Temp\?

Comment: I do not see any relation to this topic. Also the behavior you are describing seems to indicate misconfigured machine, rather than a problem with the installer. Anyway, if you want help with this, ask a question (and make sure you research it, before asking).

Comment: I tried:[Run]

 Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe /extract:{tmp}\AccRT; 
Filename: {tmp}\AccRt; Parameters: /config {tmp}\config.xml;

 Filename: {tmp}\accsp2.exe /extract:{tmp}\Accsp2; 
Filename: {tmp}\accsp2; Parameters: /config {tmp}\config.xml;

Comment: I removed the quotations from the below as they were causing a "can't find file" error and rant the Inno Setup file again without the quotes which seems to be a slight improvement but now I get an "Access denied error:

Comment: I am an administrator on the PC in question.  I removed the quotations from the Filename: {tmp}\accRt\setup.exe; Parameters: "/config ""{tmp}\config.xml"""
as they were causing a "can't find file" error and ran the Inno Setup file again without the quotes which seems to be a slight improvement but now I get an "Access denied error:  Unable to execute file C:\users\John...\AppData\Local\Temp\is-F9GVH.tmp\AccRT  Create Process failed; code 5

Comment: Filename: {tmp}\AccRt.exe; Parameters: /extract:{tmp}\AccRT /quiet 
[Files]
Source: C:\Hello\config.xml; DestDir: {tmp}
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\AccRt\setup.exe; Parameters: "/config ""{tmp}\config.xml"""           -- Run entry --
   Run as: Current user
  Type: Exec
   Filename: C:\Users\JOHN~1.COR\AppData\Local\Temp\is-AJV8S.tmp\AccRt\setup.exe
   Parameters: /config C:\Users\JOHN~1.COR\AppData\Local\Temp\is-AJV8S.tmp\config.xml
  Process exit code: 1392   Martin, I don't seem to be able to get the <ctrl+k> to indent

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com/ or similar service to share the code + We need the `config.xml` too.

Comment: Your  `config.xml` is indeed invalid XML. You cannot have another `<!--` inside comments. Why do you even distribute a configuration file with commented-out part? Remove it.